# why my formula doesn't align left with "flalign*"?

Tags: align

I want to make my formula align left, so I write like this:

```
\documentclass[UTF8]{ctexart}
\usepackage[fleqn]{lmodern,amsmath}

\title{标题}
\author{roger}
\begin{document}
公式如下:
\begin{flalign*}
d1 = (x_1, ...x_N) \\
BM25(w_i, d1) = \frac{(k+1)c(w_i, d1)}{c(w_i, d1) + k(1 - b + b\frac{|d|}{avdl})} \\
x_i = \frac{BM25(w_i, d1)}{\Sigma_{j=1}^NBM25(w_j, d1)}
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

Here is my result:
[image: this is my result]

Answer (score 5):

`flalign` is a variant of `align` but uses the full width of the page  (length of the line, hence fl). Like the other AMS alignments it is designed to set equations as pairs of columns with a left column right aligned (typically to `&=`) and a left column left aligned, and then the next two columns again being right-left aligned.

You have specified no alignment points so the entire structure is in the first, right aligned part of the first equation.

You want `&=` on each row, and perhaps use `align` rather than `flalign`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{lmodern}


\author{roger}
\begin{document}
zzz:
\begin{flalign*}
d1 = (x_1, ...x_N) \\
BM25(w_i, d1) = \frac{(k+1)c(w_i, d1)}{c(w_i, d1) + k(1 - b + b\frac{|d|}{avdl})} \\
x_i = \frac{BM25(w_i, d1)}{\Sigma_{j=1}^NBM25(w_j, d1)}
\end{flalign*}


zzz:
\begin{flalign*}
\mathrm{d1} &= (x_1, ...x_N) \\
\mathrm{BM25}(w_i, \mathrm{d1}) &= \frac{(k+1)c(w_i, \mathrm{d1})}{c(w_i, \mathrm{d1}) + k(1 - b + b\frac{|d|}{avdl})} \\
x_i &= \frac{\mathrm{BM25}(w_i, \mathrm{d1})}{\Sigma_{j=1}^N\mathrm{BM25}(w_j, \mathrm{d1})}
\end{flalign*}


zzz:
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{d1} &= (x_1, ...x_N) \\
\mathrm{BM25}(w_i, \mathrm{d1}) &= \frac{(k+1)c(w_i, \mathrm{d1})}{c(w_i, \mathrm{d1}) + k(1 - b + b\frac{|d|}{avdl})} \\
x_i &= \frac{\mathrm{BM25}(w_i, \mathrm{d1})}{\Sigma_{j=1}^N\mathrm{BM25}(w_j, \mathrm{d1})}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Blank space after display math is ok with `flalign*`?

Comment: @PeterGrill same as with any other blank line, it is a paragraph break so it is OK or not depending if you want the following `zzz` to start a paragraph. (It is _before_ a math display that you should never have a blank line)