# left align formulae; `flalign` seems not to work

Tags: align, amsmath

I want a few formulae left align (but not all in formulae in the document) and use `flalign` following [How to align a set of multiline equations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44450/how-to-align-a-set-of-multiline-equations?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

but the result shows the formula in the center. Why?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
the formula:

\noindent A \hfill Z
\begin{flalign}
1 \in N
\end{flalign}

\noindent A \hfill Z

more text 

\end{document}
```

result:
[image]

Comment: `fl` in `flalign` doesn't mean "flushleft", but rather "fill line" (or "full length"?). See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/365059/82917.

Comment: Thank you, I was obviously confused by the name. In the answer you reference and others answers, I do not see a way to have formulae left aligned without using `[fleqn]` globally (in `usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}`); I would like to have a few formulae left alginged, but not set `[fleqn]` for all). How?

Comment: For just a few equations you can use the solution proposed in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/148854/82917

Comment: A simpler solution for occasionally left aligned equations is to nest them in a `fleqn` environment (defined by package `nccmath`). See an examplein my answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/436311/left-align-text-within-alignat-and-keep-everything-else-centered/436337#436337). Furthermore, the indent of the equations is a optional argument for the environment (no indent by default).